# Error adding Google Play Services to gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services

I added this to **build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
  // ADOBE Creative SDK
  compile 'com.adobe.creativesdk.foundation:auth:0.2.10'
  compile 'com.adobe.creativesdk.foundation:assets:0.2.10'
  compile 'com.adobe.creativesdk:behance:0.2.10'
  compile 'com.adobe.creativesdk:image:4.0.0'
  // Holo Color Picker
  compile 'com.larswerkman:HoloColorPicker:1.4'
  // MultiDexApplication
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
  compile files('libs/FlurryAnalytics-5.3.0.jar')
}
```

It build and sync without any error but when I run I got this error.

app:preDexDebug FAILED

If I remove GooglePlayServices it works fine

> compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'

**Update:**
I tried many things to solve this problem but still I'm not able to solve this error.

Comment: Have you checked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26940396/android-studio-execution-failed-for-task-apppredexdebug) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25828524/android-studio-predexdebug-failed) SO question?

Comment: @Sufian I have checked but I cannot trace the reasong for it, if I remove this line that it will run. So it may be the case of duplicate library. But how to check which library is using GooglePlayServices?

Comment: use latest build tools, target and compile sdk = 21 and if you use appcompat-v7, you need 21.0.3

Comment: The tools are latest, I updated yesterday only. 
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

Comment: [This thread](https://teamtreehouse.com/forum/android-app-has-error-execution-failed-taskapppredexdebug-trying-to-test-parse-but-cant-run-app-with-this-error) might be useful.